# dns lookup with multiple ip to one name

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a server that monitors other systems across two VLANs. It is connected to them by using two NICs. nslookup from a client on either VLAN reports the IP from network B but not A. Is there something I can do so that it favors one IP instead of the other or even not have nslookup report network B's address and only show A's IP? The best case I think would for DNS to show both IPs so that both networks can reach the server by name but I'm not sure if that would cause more problems.

The intent is for admins (who sit in net A) to type the hostname into the browser or ssh to access it and not the IP.

They are both internal networks and

I don't have control over the DNS server (windows based I believe)

Server: ubuntu LTS 18.04.1

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. You could force your monitoring to IP and not DNS/Hostname
2. If your application reads it; update your /etc/hosts
3. run your own DNS server with your custom records or a split horizon

But we would need more information; what monitoring system are you using?

Comment: I'm using icinga2, the monitor picks up everything ok (not using agents). it's just for admins wanting to look at the web interface so they can use the hostname in the web browser.

Comment: Assuming your network has an External and Internal IP then the only solution would be to update your internal DNS servers and give out the right internal IP to internal users on the same network. We use the same method internally, we run a BIND server that gives out the internal IP to an internal request. Updating /etc/hosts could also accomplish this in some cases.

Comment: The same dns server actually exists on both networks. They're both internal networks but different VLANs. I'll add this to the question

Comment: I would suggest split horizon as well, but don't set up your own DNS server. Talk to the people who manage the company-wide DNS servers. Work together, you're one big company :-)